# Passing values from javascript to an MVC controller function when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an Html Button and a razor EditFor textbox. this is to add something to a database. However, i want this particular button to call a function to get information from a webservice (IMDB) in order to fill in the rest of the information. Here is what I have for the Razor Portion:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

I want to take this value and when the 'IMDB' button is clicked, i want to call the service to get the JSON. Heres my button:

```
     <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="button" id="IMDB" value="IMDB"  class="btn btn-default" onclick="AjaxDisplayString();" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is my javascript on the page:

```
<script>
    function AjaxDisplayString() {
        $.ajax({
            url: @Url.Action("CallIMDB"),
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(data) { alert(data); }
        });
    }

</script>
```

This never calls my controller function. The page does nothing. Here is my MVC controller function that is supposed to be called

```
public ActionResult CallIMDB(string title)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var json = client.DownloadString("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + title.Replace(' ', '+') + "&y=&plot=short&r=json");
    var search = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(json);
    return search;
}
```

So, to sum up. I am trying to take the Title value from my razor for editor field and pass it into the controller function to get the JSON back from IMDB web service. However, the page does nothing, and the controller function is never called.

Comment: did you examine the generated HTML? Specially the script section...

Comment: The Url should be between **' '** these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to take the "title" value, change your script like this:

```
<script>
    function AjaxDisplayString() {
        var action = '@Url.Action("CallIMDB")'; // action must be between quotes
        var title = $("#Title").val(); // get the "Title" from input text

        var url = action + "?title=" + title; // get the complete url with route values

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(data) { alert(data); }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I changed my EditFor to include an HTML helper for an ID of "Title" and replaced my script with yours. It now calls the correct function, but Title never has a value. Anything i'm doing wrong to get the title in there?

Comment: It is not necessary to define "id" tag in EditorFor helper, the helper does it itself. Let the original EditorFor.

Comment: ok. got that. looked at html source and it shows the EditFor field as blank, even when theres a value in there. For instance I type "The green mile" and hit the button. this is what the html shows:
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="" />
there is no title registering it seems

Comment: Also I made a change to script in order to send "title" as query string.

Comment: @rigamonk "value" tag is changed in virtual DOM when you type in control on screen. jQuery gets the current value from virtual DOM:  `$("#Title").val()`

Comment: Or better, use `data: { title: $("#Title").val() }`